# subprocess.check_output with sed - getting incorrect results - returns returns \x01\n

Tags: python

If I run the following in bash I get the correct results -

```
git -C /opt/Tro/ branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p'
```

It returns enhancements which is correct.

If I try to run it in a python script I get back  \x01\n

```
subprocess.check_output("git -C /opt/Tro branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p'", shell=True)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The escape sequences in your string are being processed by Python, so `\1` becomes a character with code `1`. Use a raw string to pass it through literally.

```
subprocess.check_output(r"git -C /opt/Tro branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p'", shell=True)
```

Comment: One more question - If I add a variable to it it does not work -
```
subprocess.check_output(r"git -C " + trove_local_home + "/opt/Trove/ branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p'", shell=True)
```
This now returns the x01 again.

Comment: You need `r` before the second string, not the first string. It's the one that contains `\1`.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.6, use a raw f-string instead of concatenation.

Comment: `fr"git -C {trove_local_home}/opt/Tro branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p'"`

Comment: Now I understand - the 'r' needs to go in front of the immediate quoted text string that it effects.
 Thanks all!!

Comment: What did you think, a single `r` affects all the rest of the strings in the script? All the strings on the same line?